# Unable to compile Linux on windows using Eclipse

Tags: linux

I am trying to compile Linux kernel on windows pc using eclipse. I created project as **Makefile Project with Existing Code** . When i tried to build Linux it is giving me below error

```
(Cannot run program "make": Launching failed)
```

How can I compile Linux on windows for x86.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse from build `linux kernel on windows` point of view just button "Compile" which invoke "make.exe".

To get build works you need install all tools, like compiler, GNU make, may be perl, may be some POSIX utils. Start your trip from installing GNU make:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

and run it from cmd.exe, make tells you something like "gcc" not found,
then install gcc and so on.

Comment: And even having GNU tools may not be enough, because you still are working on top of a case-insensitive filesystem without support for Linux-style file attributes.

Comment: Yeah, I almost sure that installing VirtualBox + Ubuntu + apt-get install build-essential + installing eclipse take 10x time less then configure windows host to be development environment for linux kernel

Comment: Or skip eclipse and save even more time.  The linux kernel is not designed to be configured and compiled inside any IDE.  At best, you're using one as a text editor.

Comment: There are commercial close sourced plugins for eclipse, which implement analog of `make xconfig`, have integration with jtag, kgdb, tracers etc., and of course as I know eclipse + cdt can be used for finding reference, auto completion  and so on. Yeah if eclipse will be not so slow and so fat memory hog